# PHP form not able to pass few values through GET and POST method

Tags: php, linux, apache, cakephp, cpanel

We are trying to pass values through URL in PHP. We are using GET method in web form to send form values in PHP. But it's not throwing any error and returns to  home page.
For  example:
We are having 3 pages
1) index.html (We have configured .htaccess index page as index.html)
2)input.php (it have web form with name as an input box & submit button. Form has action method=GET and  action=result)
3)result.php (it get value from URL using $_GET["value"] and display the value using echo)

When I pass url as http://samsungmobileservicecenterinchennai.com/name.php?value=having+t% from input.php it routes to index.html without displaying any error.
But when we pass same url without % at the end (i.e http://samsungmobileservicecenterinchennai.com/input.php?value=having+t%) it moves correctly to result.php and displaying the value in result.php page

```
 
For all your reference I have created 2 pages input.php and result.php

1) input.php (http://samsungmobileservicecenterinchennai.com/input.php) - pass this value in 
 name ="[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]having[/vc_column_text][/vc_tta_section][/vc_tta_accordion][/vc_column][/vc_row]" 
it will return to index page without any error.

2)pass following value in 
 name="[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]it may occur's error[/vc_column_text][/vc_tta_section][/vc_tta_accordion][/vc_column][/vc_row]" 
it moves to second page without any error.
```

When we are doing same thing in our local server it's work fine. Only in Shared web server provided by our web space hosting company it's not working. Kindly let me know how to resolve this issue.

My shared web space server details.

cPanel Version  11.50.0 (build 29)
Theme   x3
Apache Version  2.4.12
PHP Version 5.5.26
MySQL Version   5.5.42-cll
Architecture    x86_64
Operating System    linux
Shared IP Address   198.23.58.79
Path to sendmail    /usr/sbin/sendmail
Path to Perl    /usr/bin/perl
Perl Version    5.10.1
Kernel Version  2.6.32-531.29.2.lve1.3.11.10.el6.x86_64
cPanel Pro  1.0 (RC1)

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to include the actual code of the PHP pages for people to be able to help answer the question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved. The problem is with web hosting company. They have enabled "modsecurity" tool in cpanel. Once modsecurity tool disabled in cpanel the wordpress working good. Thanks for all your supports.